# Microsoft Word VBA insert web link to text box in document

Tags: vba, ms-word, hyperlink

Is there any way I can insert an html link into a textbox using VBA? I've created a dialog with a textbox, I would like to convert the text to a web link, then insert it to the textbox in the document.

```
Dim WO_Box1 As Shape
Set WO_Box1 = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=17, Top:=125, Width:=106.5, Height:=19)
WO_Box1.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "Tahoma"
WO_Box1.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = "9"
WO_Box1.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = TextBox1.Text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WO_Box1.TextFrame.TextRange.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=WO_Box1.TextFrame.TextRange, Address:=TextBox1.Text, TextToDisplay:=TextBox1.Text
```

The **Anchor** is the textbox you are working with.  You can use any text for **TextToDisplay** but the **Address** should be assigned to the actual hyperlink url.

Comment: Sorry, I was working on a separate problem in Powerpoint VBA at the same time and got confused, I have now corrected my post to show Word VBA